# createBookmarks2 in ckeditor after insertElement

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, getselection

My source code:

```
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.wiki__text;
var bookmark =     oEditor.getSelection().createBookmarks2(); // first bookmark
var html = '<'+b+' id="id_'+AInc+'">'+AInc+'</'+b+'>';
var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( html, oEditor.document );
oEditor.insertElement( newElement );
var bookmark2 = oEditor.getSelection().createBookmarks2(); // second bookmark
console.log('bm: ',bookmarks);
oEditor.getSelection().selectBookmarks( bookmark );
```

If I use `first bookmark` the cursor jumps to the position before newElement but I want to have the position after newElement. But if I use `second bookmark` I will get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null` in some ckeditor.js file

Any idea how to get the cursor postion after newElement?

Comment: Why do you create bookmarks after inserting element?

Comment: I have a full setData afterwards and I want to bookmark the cursor position after the insertElement. Or actually I want to have it after AInc and before </'+b+'>'

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a small `true`

```
var bookmark2 = oEditor.getSelection().createBookmarks2(true); // second bookmark
```